# Python 3 app crahes with 'http.client.BadStatusLine' after httpconnection.request even though exception handler present

Tags: python

I have two issues I don't understand.

The first is that I occasionally get a 'http.client.BadStatusLine' error after an httpconnection.request. 99.99% of the time the code works, but just occasionally it returns this error. So is it my code, or is it the server that's causing the problem?

The second is that I have two exception handlers in the code. The first I put around the whole subroutine to capture any coding error I might have made (the app runs headless, so I want to capture any errors and handle them in such a way so that I can record the error and terminate the app in a tidy fashion). The second is around the actual request so, again, I can capture any errors, report them and, in this case, let the app carry on. Strangely, it is the subroutine exception handler that captures the 'http.client.BadStatusLine' rather than exception handler around the request. Why is this?

I hope that (and my code snippet below) all makes sense and any thoughts, suggestions or ways to ensure I capture the 'http.client.BadStatusLine' as a recoverable error , rather than a fatal one, would be very gratefully received!!

Please forgive my coding. I am of the old school and haven't really grasped the newer ways of coding, so most of mine is like I was writing an old Fortran or VB programme!

Thanks, Jim

The code goes something like:

```
try:

    headers = {'X-Pvoutput-Apikey' : cArr[pvo_key][cVal],
               'X-Pvoutput-SystemId' : cArr[pvo_sysid][cVal],
               "Accept" : "text/plain",
               "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
    pvAddBaURL = "/service/r2/addbatchstatus.jsp"

    try:
        conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(pvo_host, timeout=ConTimeOut)
        #conn.set_debuglevel(2) # debug purposes only
        conn.request("POST", pvAddBaURL, "data=" + pvAddBaPrm, headers)
    except:
        errorReturn = sys.exc_info()
        writeLog(logWn, codeUpl, "Warning  > Batch upload connect unsuccessful")
        writeLog(logEr, codeUpl, "Bat > Batch upload unsuccessful with:")
        for errorVal in errorReturn:
            writeLog(logEr, codeUpl, "Bat > Connect error: " + str(errorVal))
        conn.close()
    else:
        response = conn.getresponse()
        if response.status != 200:
            writeLog(logWn, codeUpl, "Error   > Batch upload unsuccessful")
            writeLog(logEr, codeUpl, "Bat > Batch upload unsuccessful with:")
            writeLog(logEr, codeUpl, "Bat > Resp status: " + str(response.status))
            writeLog(logEr, codeUpl, "Bat > Resp reason: " + str(response.reason))
            writeLog(logEr, codeUpl, "Bat > Resp read: " + str(response.read()))
            conn.close()
        else:
            writeLog(logVb, codeUpl, "Bat > Upload successful")
            writeLog(logFu, codeUpl, "Bat > Resp status: " + str(response.status))
            writeLog(logFu, codeUpl, "Bat > Resp reason: " + str(response.reason))
            writeLog(logDb, codeUpl, "Bat > Resp read: " + str(response.read()))
            conn.close()

except:
    eespvo_Fatal(sys.exc_info(), codeUpl)  #fatal exception handler routine

#Routine to handle Crash!
#------------------------
#Ensures that even if there is a programming error the app can report it in the log.

def eespvo_Fatal(crashData, mod):

    writeLog(logWn, codeFaE, "Fatal    > eespvo (ProcId: "
         + str(eespvo_pid) +") terminated - restart attempted")
    writeLog(logFa, codeFaE, "Ftl > Fatal: eespvo crashed (ProcId: "
         + str(eespvo_pid) + ", Module: " + mod)

    for crashVal in crashData:
        writeLog(logFa, codeFaE, "Ftl > Fatal: " + str(crashVal))

    for frame in traceback.extract_tb(crashData[2]):
        fname, lineno, fn, text = frame
    writeLog(logFa, codeFaE, "Ftl > Fatal: <traceback line: " + str(lineno) + ">")
    writeLog(logFa, codeFaE, "Ftl > Fatal: <traceback module: " + str(fn) + ">")       
    writeLog(logFa, codeFaE, "Ftl > Fatal: <traceback text: " + str(text) + ">")

    writeLog(logFa, codeFaE, "Ftl > Fatal: eespvo (ProcId: " + str(eespvo_pid)
         +") killed")
    cArr[runOK][cVal] = False

#kill our own process
    os.kill(eespvo_pid,signal.SIGKILL)
```

The output from my logs looks something like this:

From the subroutine exception handler:

```
20141216 084503 X: FaE - Ftl > Fatal: eespvo crashed (ProcId: 2380, Module: Upl
20141216 084503 X: FaE - Ftl > Fatal: <class 'http.client.BadStatusLine'>
20141216 084503 X: FaE - Ftl > Fatal: ''
20141216 084503 X: FaE - Ftl > Fatal: <traceback object at 0xe490d0>
20141216 084503 X: FaE - Ftl > Fatal: <traceback line: 316>
20141216 084503 X: FaE - Ftl > Fatal: <traceback module: _read_status>
20141216 084503 X: FaE - Ftl > Fatal: <traceback text: raise BadStatusLine(line)>
20141216 084503 X: FaE - Ftl > Fatal: eespvo (ProcId: 2380) killed
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I still don't know the answer to question 1. But I think I might have solved question 2. I think the problem is that it is the statement:

```
response = conn.getresponse()
```

which is failing. Being outside the request exception handling it fails to the subroutine exception handling. So the solution is to put it within the request exception handling, vis:

```
    try:
        conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(pvo_host, timeout=ConTimeOut)
        #conn.set_debuglevel(2) # debug purposes only
        conn.request("POST", pvAddBaURL, "data=" + pvAddBaPrm, headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
    except:
```

Only time will tell!